# request - response strategy through Messaging System (kafka/.NET)

Tags: python, asp.net-core, apache-kafka, memorycache

I am moving a distributed architecture from Python to .NetCore. This architecture has a Gateway API that pushes the requests to a Service Bus (KAFKA). The requests are treated by Microservices. These microservices answer to the Gateway (then to the client) on a topic set in the request object. 
The topic name is build based on the process_id of the python Application (Flask/uwsgi).

But with .NetCore Webapi application, I cannot find a way to get 'topics' from its process (I am beginning in .NetCore). Using Async method to free the entry point while waiting for a microservices answer, the best would be to generate topic name based on kind of Assembly ID. But every Asyc method call would generate different topic, right? That would lead in a high number of topics... Kind of weird...

Do you see any other way to proceed?

I am thinking about using a MemoryCache to wrap the communication between answers from Microservices and Gateway process. (the request would contain a Guid, used as a key for memory cache access). What do you think?

Comment: Why not just continue to use process id?

```Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();```
```p.Id.ToString();```

Comment: I don't know how is handled 'Tasks' and async function in .NET. The interest in python and process identifier was (to my mind), that once started, the process ID never changes. Then a single process can always manage only one Topic. In .NET, I guess that invoking a potential `await FetchClientResponseAsync()` would generate a new process, leading to a new topic. Multiple access would then lead to many and many topics, which I feel not very confortable with (readability, topic only used for so few 1 messages...)

Answer (score 0):

This code outputs the same number, so tasks do inherit the process_id of the main process.  The thread_id is probably different.

You might also consider using a GUID, rather than process_id.  Just a thought.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class s
    {
        public s() { }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
        Task.Run(async () => { bool x = await Go(); }).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); ;
        }  

        private static Task<bool> Go()
        {
        Console.WriteLine(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
        return Task.FromResult<bool>(false);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah OK, thank you. Do you then agree that collecting, an answer from one 'async' task, allow my webapp to receive and manage another client  request, potentially leading to contact services once again and enter a similar receive response loop? This way, I would have two tasks waiting for the same kind of response on the same topic, leading to potential corruption ?

Comment: Also, `Guid` generate unique values, right? This would help each task to collect its private response. This would be better, even if the result would lead to a huge amount of topics ...

Comment: Based on my limited understanding of your application, yes, I can see two tasks waiting for the same topic (process_id).  GUIDs are said to globally unique.  The scope of global is very broad, but for sure within your application they will be unique.